# Composer on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, composer

I installed Composer from http://getcomposer.org in my computer with Windows 7 and xampp as web server. I want to know if there is a way to verify that the installation was successful. Is there a command I can run from the console to verify this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From command prompt (Start -> Run -> cmd.exe) run:

> C:\Users\username>composer -V

You should see:

> Composer version 1.0.0 2016-01-10 20:34:53

it's part of the install manual: [composer installer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#using-the-installer)